# How to get additional attributes from Azure AD through Keycloak social login

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak

I have a multitenant web application which uses Keycloak for authentication. Keycloak forwards authentication requests to various identity providers. Tenants that use Azure AD for authentication can press on 'log in with microsoft' and are forwarded to the Microsoft login solution. Other users can use Google or a number of SAML2 identity providers.

Problem: i want to receive some additional user attributes that are not provided by default by Azure.

- The microsoft social login identity provider in Keycloak worked after some fiddling but i was unable to add user defined attributes to the ID or access token. After some more fiddling the log file on Keycloak shows the social login json that is returned by Azure, but it only contains the obvious attributes (email, first name etc).
- A SAML2 identity provider in Keycloak works and allows me to additional attributes, but requires configuration of each tenant-id in Azure.
- In comparison, the google equivalent works out of the box.

What is a straightforward way to send users from Keycloak to Azure to authenticate and receive user attributes back?

Any help is appreciated, i find the multitude of Azure options and its terminoloy quite confusing.

Comment: Did you get chance to look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims)? Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this requires a multitenant Azure Enterprise app definition: More details here: [Azure AD How to pass userextension attributes to multitenant app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054989/azure-ad-how-to-pass-userextension-attributes-to-multitenant-app/63066969#63066969)