# Azure AD How to pass userextension attributes to multitenant app

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, multi-tenant

In Azure AD i have a multi-tenant Enterprise Application and App registration that are accessed through SAML2. I receive a limited set of users attributes, including tenant-id, email, first name, last name. But the organisation that the user belongs to, has defined extension attributes in their on-premise AD that i want to consume in my application. Also i would like to receive the jobTitle and Department in the application. The organisation says they have set up synchonisation of the attributes from their on-premise AD to Azure.

I have added the attributes i want under the Enterprise Application -> Single sign-on -> User Attributes and Claims -> Additional claims.  But i am obviously still missing some configuration somewhere because they do not appear in the SAML2 token.

Which API permissions do i need to grant my application to pass these attributes through to the SAML2 token? Do i need to add something else to map these attributes?

Answer (score 1):

when you set up a multitenant app, when your client's users / tenant signs in, it actually creates an "enterprise application" (service principal) in their tenant for your app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent

As per that, your client would have to go into the SSO (saml) setup screens for your app in their own tenant and customize the claims that they will emit to your application. It doesn't matter if you add the attribute claims to your own SSO setup. thats for your tenant, not theirs.

Comment: I set up a separate Azure account to test, but when i use the https://login.microsoftonline.com/[customer Tenant]/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=...  url to allow consent for the organisation i can see the enterprise app in the customer Tenant, but it does not have the 'Set up single Sign on' section in any of the tabs. Does that need to be enable somewhere?

The sso screen is visible in the Application owning Tenant.

Comment: Trawled through the Microsoft docs and found "Other scenarios where Single sign-on will be missing from the navigation include when an application is hosted in another tenant or if your account does not have the required permissions (Global Administrator, Cloud Application Administrator, Application Administrator, or owner of the service principal). ".

So it seems you can only edit the single sign on attributes if you own the application. Was this a dead end?

Comment: hmm it's not  quite a dead end, though you are right. apparently it doesnt because by default it will create oidc supported app, if this is the case, then you would have to delete it and manually create a non-gallery enterprise application, then you will have the SSO options, but then you'll have to set up the SAML profile manually in the client tenant

Comment: Is there any way to configure the app to create SAML supported Service Principals? If i remove the Service principal in the client  tenant they will have to go through the whole configuration process, which is painful

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Single Sign On properties are not visible in the Service Principal, because the proper tags are not set in the Application registration.

After using Microsoft Graph Explorer to see the properties of a working Service Principal with SSO properties, i noticed that it had a tag set that was absent in the Service Principal without SSO properties in the portal.

In the Application Registration manifest i set:

```
"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",
"tags": [
        "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryCustomSingleSignOnApplication",
        "webApp",
        "notApiConsumer"
],
```

Then recreated the service principal in a guest tenant using an adminconsent link ([https://login.microsoftonline.com/[guest](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5Bguest) tenant domain]/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=[app registration id]...) the portal displayed the Single Sign On settings in the guest tenant.

The Azure portal seems to display SSO properties for Service Principals associated with Application registrations that have the WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryCustomSingleSignOnApplication tag.

To summarise:

- Set the WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryCustomSingleSignOnApplication tag in the Application registration manifest.
- Create a Service Principal in the Owning Tenant if you haven't done that already.
- Use an adminconsent url to create a Service Principal in the Guest tenant.
- Have the Guest Tenant Administrator fill in the single sign on properties to add the required attributes.

The attributes are returned to the application in the SAML2 token